# Displaying Call for Price on configurable products

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have many configurable products on a site and some of the options on those

products need to say **Call for Price** instead of having a price.

From a previous question I added the following code:

```
<?php if ($_product->getFinalPrice() == 0) : ?>
<h2>Call For Price</h2>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This works for simple products but not for configurables because it doesn't change when the ajax updates the price.

Comment: Nothing so far, I'm still looking for the code where it changes the price through ajax. I'm more of a front end developer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late answer but may be some one get help by my answer.

Create an `Yes/No attribute (call_for_price)` for Call For Price.

Now modify your price template files for do not show the price if it Call For Price is set to 'Yes'. 
Open `price.phtml` **app/design/frontend/theme_package/theme/template/catalog/product/** of your template file if it not exist in your theme copy it from base theme.
And find this line

`$_product = $this->getProduct();`   after this line just put this code:

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
if($_product->getCallForPrice()==1){
    echo 'Call For price';
    return;
}
```

save the file clear your cache.

Done!